# CSS subchild selector

Tags: html, css, selector

Both of the following codes seem to work properly to style the `span` element:

```
<style>
    div p span {
        font: 18px arial;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <p>
        <span>
            Hello, world!
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

```
<style>
    div span {
        font: 18px arial;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <p>
        <span>
            Hello, world!
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

But I'm not sure if the second one is the right coding and if there's a difference between them, for example regarding browser support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it really depends on the context. For example, this selector...

```
div p span
```

will only apply to all `span` elements that are children of a `p` element which in turn, are children of a `div` element. Consider, this html...

```
<div>
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="desc">Description</span>
    <p>
        <span>Content</span>
    <p>
</div>
```

the following css declaration will color the content span in blue

```
div p span
{
    color:Blue;
}
```

however the style is not applied to the title and the description because they are not children of a `p` element. Now by using this css declaration...

```
div span
{
    color:Blue;
}
```

will cause both the title, description and the content to be coloured in blue because this selector targets all `span` elements that are nested within a `div` element

As for performance, that's hard to determine because it all depends on implementation and how well different browsers traverse through a DOM hierarchy and apply the style. But, I'd guess that the more specific you can be the better so that the HTML parser can target elements directly. With that in mind, this css selector...

```
div p span
```

should perform faster than

```
div span
```

because it will cause the rendering engine to look for all `div` element, then `p` elements ignoring all other elements (including `span` elements that are direct children) and finally it'll look for `span` elements

Answer (score 2):

Neither of them is a “subchild selector”; there is no such concept in CSS. They are different descendant selectors, or [descendant combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) as they are called in the *Selectors Level 3* specification. Their meanings are different, so it depends on the purpose which one is better.

The selector `div span` matches any `span` element that is a descendant of a `div` element. The selector `div p span` matches any `span` element that is a descendant of a `p` element that is a descendant of a `div` element. Both selectors are rather theoretical as such; they are hardly useful in practical situations without some additional components such as class selectors.

Answer (score 1):

They both work because the elements selected by `div p span` are a subset of the ones selected by `div span`.

If you include a `<span>` as a child of the `<div>`, the second one will select it, but the first one will not. If you don't include a `<span>` as a child of the `<div>`, they will select exactly the same elements.

For example:

```
<div>
    <span>Only the second selector will make this text red</span>

    <p>
        <span>Hello, world!</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

both of them will work but

```
div p span {
    font: 18px arial;
    color: red;
}
```

is more correct, and you are less likely to have problems like when you decide to add a span in an li for some other possible purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
div > p > span {
 font: 18px arial;
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First method is correct way.The styles work only span that inside of the p tag and you can give/edit/change specific styles on this item ...but the second method's style work all span inside of div tag..